# How to get rows in relations many-to-many?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have three tables:

```
object | product | object_product



object         product        object_product
______         _______        ______________
id title       id title       id_object  id_product
1  Maga        1  Cola        1          1
```

I have the following query builder:

```
$products = Product::with("categories.names")->where(function ($query) use ($request) {

})->with('images')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($limit)->toArray();
```

I need to get all products of selected object `place_id`.

I tried to do this in constructor query body:

```
if (($request->get("place_id"))) {
   // HERE JOIN TO TABLE object_product
}
```

But

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: $products = Product::join('object_product', function($q) use ($request) { $q->whereRaw('products.id = object_product.id_product'); $q->where('object_product.id_product', $request->get('place_id'); })->with...

Comment: How can I do this using `with` or with `wherehas`?

Comment: maybe "whereExists" when